# How to replace duplicate elements as 0 in column matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to replace the repeated elements in column of a matrix as 0's and delete the rows which has all 0's. If my matrix is like this means.
     Input =

```
 1     0     0     1     
 0     1     0     1     
 0     0     1     1     
 1     1     1     1
```

My expected output should be like this

Output =

```
 1     0     0     1     
 0     1     0     0     
 0     0     1     0     
 0     0     0     0  ---> this row should be get deleted in this case
```

This doesn't work for my problem

```
 c = [ 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0];    
 [c, ic] = unique(a, 'first');
 c(~ismember(1:length(a),ic)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical indexing and cumsum:

```
 A = [1     0     0     1;    
      0     1     0     1;     
      0     0     1     1;     
      1     1     1     1];


ind            = cumsum(A); %cumulative sum (by column)
A(ind>1)       = 0;         
A(sum(A')==0,:)=[]
```